# Stand-alone musaf

Tags: tefilla, rosh-chodesh-new-month, musaf

Last *rosh chodesh,* due to a case of emergency, I had to conclude my morning prayer with *Aleinu* after having said *Ashrei* and *Uva leTziyon.* So instead of proceeding with the *musaf,* I had to recuperate it later that day, which practically meant that I had to say it on its own. Since we learn it in [Berakhot 32a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.32a.32) (see also [Tur Orach Chayim 51](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A0%D7%90)) that we should not start right with our prayers, but first we should say some praise of *Hashem,* I was wondering what shall someone do in a similar situation? Should one repeat *Ashrei* before the *amidah?* May one recite [Psalm 104](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26a4.htm) instead? Do you have to say *Uva leTziyon* at some point again? (I assume *Aleinu* should be said after in any case.) I would much appreciate sources!

Comment: The simplest analogue is Ne'ilah where you indeed just open with Ashrei (at least for Sefardim).

Comment: could one append it to mincha?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75221/759

Comment: I suspect it has to do with timing. Is it yet mincha time? If so, I imagine you'd daven mincha first (tadir v'she'eino tadir...) as @rosends suggested. If not, I guess you'd probably start with Ashrei as you and DoubleAA suggested.

Comment: @Daniel Timing is a different story, and it is already discussed in the question linked in comment.

Comment: @Daniel even if you daven mincha first the question remains what to do after mincha before musaf